# Tag dispatching - couldn't infer template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I wanted to merge two STL containers, e.g. vector and forward_list. Goal is to be able to pass in vector or forward_list as first argument and via tag dispatching getting the right function.

```
template <typename F, typename S>
F __merge(F first, S second, std::random_access_iterator_tag dummy){
    F _new_;
    return std::merge(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), std::back_inserter(_new_));
}

template <typename F, typename S>
S __merge(F first, S second, std::forward_iterator_tag dummy){
    S _new_;
    return std::merge(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), std::back_inserter(_new_));
}



template <typename F, typename S, typename P>
P merge(F first, S second){
    typedef typename F::iterator_category cat1;
    P result = __merge(first, second, cat1());
    return result;
```

Calling the function:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
std::forward_list<int> e = {44,55,66};
auto r = merge<std::vector<int>, std::forward_list<int > >(a,e);
```

Can somebody help, why the compiler is not able to infer the template argument P.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'merge'
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'P'
```

_______________ **********EDIT********** ________________

using auto instead of P solves that problem.

```
template <typename F, typename S>
    auto merge(F first, S second){
        typedef typename F::iterator_category cat1;
        auto result = __merge(first, second, cat1());
        return result;
```

However this problem remains:

```
no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int>>'
```

This problem is solved by using

```
using cat1 = typename F::iterator::iterator_category;
```

Additionally another problem occurred:

> error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
> 'std::__1::back_insert_iterator<std::__1::vector<int,
> std::__1::allocator > >' to function return type
> 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator >'

This was solved by not returning the expression of std::merge but return the changed *new* container (it was changed in-place).

```
template <typename F, typename S>
S __merge(F first, S second, std::forward_iterator_tag dummy){
    S _new_;
    std::merge(first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), std::back_inserter(_new_));
    return _new_;
}
```

The goal of:

> I wanted to merge two STL containers, e.g. vector and forward_list.
> Goal is to be able to pass in vector or forward_list as first argument
> and via tag dispatching getting the right function.

is achieved.

Comment: Why can't you use `auto`, in place of `P` ???

Comment: thanks, this solves this specific problem, didn't know that this is possible @pvc

Comment: "However this problem remains:" - The base class `std::iterator` (that contains a `iterator_category` member type) it's deprecated starting from C++17 (see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator))

Comment: @max66 How would one distinguish then between the two cases ?

Comment: @YvesBoutellier - Sorry: my comment was correct but irrelevant; your error, with `cat1`, was that your trying to extract `iterator_category` from the containers when you have to extract it from the iterators; so `using cat1 = typename F::iterator::iterator_category;` or also `using cat1 = typename decltype(first.begin())::iterator_category;`

Comment: @max66 this helps, thank you very much. An additional problem was that with my use std::merge and std::back_inserter(_new_) I shouldn't return, but it changes in place